# Appending or Adding Rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, append, pivot-table

In the following DataFrame I would like to add rows if the count of values in the column A is less than 10.

For eg., in the following Table column A group 60 appears 12 times, however gorup 61 appears 9 times. I would like to add a row after last record of group 61 and copy the value in column B,C,D from the corresponding values group 60. Similar operation for group 62 and so on.

```
     A       B   C      D
0   60   0.235   4   7.86
1   60   1.235   5   8.86
2   60   2.235   6   9.86
3   60   3.235   7  10.86
4   60   4.235   8  11.86
5   60   5.235   9  12.86
6   60   6.235  10  13.86
7   60   7.235  11  14.86
8   60   8.235  12  15.86
9   60   9.235  13  16.86
10  60  10.235  14  17.86
11  60  11.235  15  18.86
12  61  12.235  16  19.86
13  61  13.235  17  20.86
14  61  14.235  18  21.86
15  61  15.235  19  22.86
16  61  16.235  20  23.86
17  61  17.235  21  24.86
18  61  18.235  22  25.86
19  61  19.235  23  26.86
20  61  20.235  24  27.86
21  62  20.235  24  28.86
22  62  20.235  24  29.86
23  62  20.235  24  30.86
24  62  20.235  24  31.86
25  62  20.235  24  32.86
```

Comment: Can you show your efforts, also you should post raw text and code rather than images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#cumulative count per group
df['G'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount()

df = df.groupby(['A','G'])
       .first()   #agregate first
       .unstack() #reshape DataFrame
       .ffill()   #same as fillna(method='ffill')
       .stack()   #get original shape
       .reset_index(drop=True, level=1) #remove level G in index
       .reset_index() 

print (df)
```

```
     A       B     C      D
0   60   0.235   4.0   7.86
1   60   1.235   5.0   8.86
2   60   2.235   6.0   9.86
3   60   3.235   7.0  10.86
4   60   4.235   8.0  11.86
5   60   5.235   9.0  12.86
6   60   6.235  10.0  13.86
7   60   7.235  11.0  14.86
8   60   8.235  12.0  15.86
9   60   9.235  13.0  16.86
10  60  10.235  14.0  17.86
11  60  11.235  15.0  18.86
12  61  12.235  16.0  19.86
13  61  13.235  17.0  20.86
14  61  14.235  18.0  21.86
15  61  15.235  19.0  22.86
16  61  16.235  20.0  23.86
17  61  17.235  21.0  24.86
18  61  18.235  22.0  25.86
19  61  19.235  23.0  26.86
20  61  20.235  24.0  27.86
21  61   9.235  13.0  16.86
22  61  10.235  14.0  17.86
23  61  11.235  15.0  18.86
24  62  20.235  24.0  28.86
25  62  20.235  24.0  29.86
26  62  20.235  24.0  30.86
27  62  20.235  24.0  31.86
28  62  20.235  24.0  32.86
29  62  17.235  21.0  24.86
30  62  18.235  22.0  25.86
31  62  19.235  23.0  26.86
32  62  20.235  24.0  27.86
33  62   9.235  13.0  16.86
34  62  10.235  14.0  17.86
35  62  11.235  15.0  18.86
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['G'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount()

df = df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='G')
       .ffill()
       .stack()
       .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
       .reset_index() 

print (df)
```

```
     A       B     C      D
0   60   0.235   4.0   7.86
1   60   1.235   5.0   8.86
2   60   2.235   6.0   9.86
3   60   3.235   7.0  10.86
4   60   4.235   8.0  11.86
5   60   5.235   9.0  12.86
6   60   6.235  10.0  13.86
7   60   7.235  11.0  14.86
8   60   8.235  12.0  15.86
9   60   9.235  13.0  16.86
10  60  10.235  14.0  17.86
11  60  11.235  15.0  18.86
12  61  12.235  16.0  19.86
13  61  13.235  17.0  20.86
14  61  14.235  18.0  21.86
15  61  15.235  19.0  22.86
16  61  16.235  20.0  23.86
17  61  17.235  21.0  24.86
18  61  18.235  22.0  25.86
19  61  19.235  23.0  26.86
20  61  20.235  24.0  27.86
21  61   9.235  13.0  16.86
22  61  10.235  14.0  17.86
23  61  11.235  15.0  18.86
24  62  20.235  24.0  28.86
25  62  20.235  24.0  29.86
26  62  20.235  24.0  30.86
27  62  20.235  24.0  31.86
28  62  20.235  24.0  32.86
29  62  17.235  21.0  24.86
30  62  18.235  22.0  25.86
31  62  19.235  23.0  26.86
32  62  20.235  24.0  27.86
33  62   9.235  13.0  16.86
34  62  10.235  14.0  17.86
35  62  11.235  15.0  18.86
```